# How to allow dynamically created file to be downloaded in CherryPy?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm trying to use CherryPy for a simple website, having never done Python web programming before.

I'm stuck trying to allow the download of a file that is dynamically created. I can create a file and return it from the handler, or call `serve_fileobj()` on the file, but in either case the contents of the file are simply rendered to the screen, rather than downloaded.

Does CherryPy offer any useful methods here? How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="<file>"'` header to response

Comment: Sounds good, I'll test it tonight or tomorrow morning, and accept if it works.

Comment: serve_fileobj(fileobj, content_type=None, disposition=None, name=None): Specify desposition, name and content_type correctly

Answer (score 3):

If you set the correct content type, you won't have to worry about it rendering in the browser when you return it *unless it's appropriate*.  Try:

```
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/foo'
```

(or whatever the correct MIME type for your content is) before you return the content.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the previous answers from @varela and @JasonFruit together:

```
dynamic_content = "this was generated on the fly!"
cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="<file>"'
return dynamic_content
```